# How do I find out what distribution this is and what the parameter is?

Tags: statistics, normal-distribution

I have a Stats question that goes like this:

Say you have `n = 100` many Xi's, where the Xi's are independent and identically distributed Bernoulli random variables with `p = 0.5 (E(X)=p and var(X)=p(1-p))`

What distribution does
[image]
follow exactly? State the type of distribution and what the
parameter is

I have no idea how to approach the question, I figure because of the Bernoulli random variable the answer is a binomial distribution? Or is this question referring to the sampling distribution, which would mean the answer is a normal distribution?

Comment: You're right. It's binomial. And n and p are given in the question.

Comment: @MaxFreiburghaus what could "the parameter" be though? Would you think this is just mu?

Comment: @unicornication The pmf is $f_X(x)=\binom{n}{x}\cdot 0.5^x$ Thus the parameter is $n$.

Comment: If the $X_i$ are either 0 or 1 (probability 1/2 each) and $Y = \sum_{i=0}^{100}X_i$ then $Y$ is Binomial with parameters $n = 100$ and $p = 1/2.$